# How to import in mongo database

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to import mongo db which I has downloaded from a website and right now I want to import it in my mongo db on my computer ( localhost ).

I'm trying to do that with a command:

```
mongodump --dbpath C:\DEVmttse
```

And below is error message which I got:

```
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.410 [tools] all dbs
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.411 dbexit:
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.411 [tools] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.415 [tools] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.418 [tools] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.422 [tools] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.425 [tools] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.429 [tools] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.432 [tools] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Apr 01 10:55:23.436 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Could you tell me what I do wrong?

Remember that I'm newbie and I didn't use mongo DB before, so thanks for understanding and every kind of help will be appreciated...

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the format of your dump ? also mongodump is wrong command to import, for importing it is mongoimport.  Link : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

Comment: Is is folder which contains more than 10 jSON files...

Comment: Hm.. I can't see how I can import all files by one command? Is it possible? I'm pretty sure how it is but I don't know how to do that, but I really don't want to go one by one..

Comment: have you tried with your directory in file option, maybe it works !

Comment: otherwise : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609647/import-more-than-1-json-file-using-mongoimport