# Import many JSON files into MongoDB with mongoimport

Tags: json, linux, mongodb, mongoimport

I use Linux, and in a local folder I have myriad of files (with **no extension**, but they are JSON array files).

I would like to import all of them into the database (`coches`) and collection (`dtc`) created in mongo.

I tried several codes found in different questions ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823876/loop-over-json-files-inside-subdirectories), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609647/import-more-than-1-json-file-using-mongoimport)) with no success. This is a list of files found in my local folder, but there are many more.

```
/media/mario/prueba/2020-02-25_00-30-33_588844_0Auy
/media/mario/prueba/2020-02-25_06-26-02_816819_KXbU
/media/mario/prueba/2020-02-25_07-07-22_868748_DCmL
/media/mario/prueba/2020-02-25_16-02-12_371020_eYjf
```

This is an example I tried unsuccessfully:

```
for filename in *; do mongoimport -db coches --collection dtc --file "$filename"  done;
```

I am new no Mongo and would like to know how to deal with this situation.

How can I import plenty of JSON files (unextensioned) to the database `coches` and collection `dtc`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'unsuccessfully'? What error did you get?
What happens when you do it for just one file? 'mongoimport --db coches --collection dtc --file <file>'

Comment: The **semicolon** should be after `"$filename"` rather than done.